# Filter key-value pairs from JSON data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have JSON data. I need only specific key-value pairs to be passed as data to a component. I used `delete` and deleted existing key-value pair except what I needed so that after deleting, only key-value pairs that I needed would exist. I got my code working perfectly but, I'm not satisfied by using `delete`  to make my code work. I need the JSON data filtered with the key-value pairs that I specify.

JSON data will be like,

```
commentProps = {
    comments:"example",
    author:"authorName",
    ownerId:"1029989",
    objectId:"152039900"
};
```

Code that I'm using right now,

```
renderItem={props => {
            const commentProps = Object.assign({}, props);
            delete commentProps.ownerId;
            delete commentProps.objectId;
            return <Comment {...commentProps}/>
        }}
```

This returns JSON data as,

```
commentProps = {comments:"example",author:"authorName"};
```

I need this to achieve without using delete. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**// Using rest operator ignore delete props:**

```
renderItem = props => {
      const {ownerId, objectId, ...rest} = props
    return <Comment {...rest} />;
  };
```

**// Best and reccomended, you should not let go all props:**

```
renderItem = props => {
      const {comments, author} = props
    return <Comment comments={comments} author={author} />;
  };
```

**With your solution**

```
renderItem={props => {
            const commentProps = Object.assign({}, {comments: props.comments, author: props.author});

            return <Comment {...commentProps}/>
        }}
```

Comment: Yup.. It worked. All three works fine. I'm satisfied with the second solution. Still wondering if it is possible with `filter`.

Comment: Great.. Thanks Mate!! :)